Remove titles from spotfire legend
Using Spotfire Analyst 14.
I have a chart onto which I've added some lines (Avg, Std Deviations, trend.) I have those lines showing on the legend, but each is prefixed with a title, or header. I.e. Horizontal Line: Average followed by Horizontal line: 3 Std Deviations with the word Horizontal Line repeated.
Is there any way to remove the words Horizontal line:? It doesn't add value, just clutter.
I have gone into properties, and manually changed the names - but the title Horizontal line: still appears.



